# MSVC 2019 Compilation failing with weird error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to compile a CMake project in Visual Studio 2019. The project compiles fine with MinGW-w64 compiler ( [this one](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/8.1.0/threads-posix/sjlj/) to be exact ) but somehow goes haywire on attempting to compile it with MSVC.
I have searched and searched but there does not seem to be any clear indication, or even a list of possibilities that can trigger an error of this sort. Here is the build log :

```
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\iphlpapi.h(1004,10): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\iphlpapi.h(1004,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'NET_LUID' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\iphlpapi.h(1012,10): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\build\src\myproject_lib.vcxprojonnector_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\iphlpapi.h(1012,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'NET_LUID' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\iphlpapi.h(1020,10): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\build\src\myproject_lib.vcxprojonnector_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\iphlpapi.h(1020,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'NET_LUID' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(801,10): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(801,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'MIB_UNICASTIPADDRESS_ROW' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(837,10): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(837,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'MIB_UNICASTIPADDRESS_ROW' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(1068,10): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(1068,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'MIB_UNICASTIPADDRESS_ROW' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(1127,10): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(1127,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'MIB_ANYCASTIPADDRESS_ROW' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(1158,10): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(1158,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'MIB_ANYCASTIPADDRESS_ROW' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(1424,10): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(1424,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'MIB_IPFORWARD_ROW2' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(1461,10): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(1461,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'MIB_IPFORWARD_ROW2' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(1501,14): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'CONST' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(1724,10): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(1724,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'MIB_IPFORWARD_ROW2' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(1963,10): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(1963,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'MIB_IPNET_ROW2' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(1995,10): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(1995,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'MIB_IPNET_ROW2' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(2138,14): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'CONST' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(2409,10): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(2409,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'GUID' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(2465,12): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(2465,18): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'CHAR' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(2493,12): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(2493,18): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'WCHAR' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(2521,10): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(2521,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'NET_LUID' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(2552,10): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(2552,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'NET_LUID' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(2583,10): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(2583,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'NET_LUID' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(2639,10): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(2639,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'NET_LUID' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(2670,12): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(2670,18): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'WCHAR' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(2698,10): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(2698,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'NET_LUID' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(2726,10): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(2726,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'GUID' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(3049,10): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(3049,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'NET_IF_NETWORK_GUID' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(3086,10): error C2065: 'CONST': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\netioapi.h(3086,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'NET_IF_NETWORK_GUID' [C:\Users\User\Project\build\src\my_proj_lib.vcxproj]
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: My guess would be an incorrectly included windows header file. The Windows API is very fussy about which header files you include and in what order. Could you edit the question to show the header files being included when yuo get this error.

Comment: That's not a stack trace BTW, it's a build log.

Comment: @john thank you for the hint. I will check the include headers :) and you're right. It is a build log, I will edit my post to reflect that.

Comment: @doa4321 if it is a header file problem with Windows header files - make sure that <windows.h> is the first MS-Windows header file included before any other MS-WIndows header files.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal  reproducible   example? Will the problem reproduce if  you create a Visual Studio project without using CMake?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT the problem is that the entire codebase is proprietary, so I cannot create a MRE without giving away what I am trying to do. I'm not an expert in CMake or Visual Studio compiler - but I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Any updates? The errors you provided belong to the SDK file. It is hard to  know what the exact error is without  minimal sample.

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT I wrote a dependency walker to figure out the dependencies. Windows.h is in fact the first MS-Windows header file included before any other MS-Windows header files, but it still did not resolve the problem. I have another much experienced senior colleague looking into the problem though.